# Creating seekbar dynamically and giving listeners for that but it is not working properly

Tags: android, android-inflate, android-seekbar

I am inflating the seekbar dynamically,but if i press the first seekbar, listener changing the values from last seek bar only .

```
for (int i = 0; i < controlList.size(); i++) {
            view1 = seekbar_inflate.inflate(R.layout.mysxm_control_coloumn, null, false);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) view1
                    .findViewById(R.id.sliderLayout);
            vertical_seekbar=new VerticalSeekBar(MyApplication.getAppContext());
            vertical_seekbar.setId(i);
            final int id = vertical_seekbar.getId();
            vertical_seekbar.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sxm_selector_column));
            frame.addView(vertical_seekbar, params);
            vertical_seekbar=(VerticalSeekBar)view1.findViewById(id);
            equalizer_view.addView(view1);
            vertical_seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar,
                        int progress, boolean arg2) {


                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


                }
            });
        }
```

how to give the listeners for each seek bar? pls suggest some answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just slight modification in my code,In this what i have realized android every widgets working based on id only.In this code you can differentiate the seekbar variable like vertical_seekbar and vertical_seekbar1 for me this the solution.Still this solution very strange for me.

```
for (int i = 0; i < controlList.size(); i++) {
                view1 = seekbar_inflate.inflate(R.layout.mysxm_control_coloumn, null, false);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) view1
                        .findViewById(R.id.sliderLayout);
                vertical_seekbar=new VerticalSeekBar(MyApplication.getAppContext());
                vertical_seekbar.setId(i);
                final int id = vertical_seekbar.getId();
                vertical_seekbar.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sxm_selector_column));
                frame.addView(vertical_seekbar, params);
                vertical_seekbar1=(VerticalSeekBar)view1.findViewById(id);
                equalizer_view.addView(view1);
                vertical_seekbar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar,
                            int progress, boolean arg2) {


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


                    }
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make vertical_seekbar and view1 as local variables. You have made them as instance so they only persist the value of last iteration, that's why your last seek bar is only working.

```
for (int i = 0; i < controlList.size(); i++) {
            View view1 = seekbar_inflate.inflate(R.layout.mysxm_control_coloumn, null, false);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) view1
                    .findViewById(R.id.sliderLayout);
            VerticalSeekBar vertical_seekbar=new VerticalSeekBar(MyApplication.getAppContext());
            vertical_seekbar.setId(i);
            final int id = vertical_seekbar.getId();
            vertical_seekbar.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sxm_selector_column));
            frame.addView(vertical_seekbar, params);
            vertical_seekbar=(VerticalSeekBar)view1.findViewById(id);
            equalizer_view.addView(view1);
            vertical_seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar,
                        int progress, boolean arg2) {


                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


                }
            });
        }
```